# Why does my skillet burn even when using peanut oil?

Tags: oil, skillet

When I use peanut oil which is one of the highest smoke point oils the oil still burns. Why is this happening? Is it the burner that's too hot? I have used the burner mainly on high

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that the flame on the gas stove was to strong so I will try lowering the flame.

Answer (score 9):

Just because peanut oil has a higher smoke point than other oils doesn't mean your pan won't get hotter.

Don't leave your pan on high for so long.

Answer (score 1):

You want the pan to be HOT when you add the oil, then add the food and turn the heat down to a moderate cooking temperature. You can drop a drop of water into the pan before the oil, if it skitters around, the pan is hot enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should never cook on high for more than a few minutes. High heat is only for brief searing and boiling water. Teflon coated skillet should never be used on high heat due to the release of carcinogens being released at high heat.

Answer (score 0):

Peanut oil isn't even the highest smoke point oil around, some highly refined safflower or soybean oils, and rice bran oil, go higher... the reason peanut oil is so good for high heat cooking is that it tends not to become unpalatable if some of it gets overheated...